# Boost multithreading exception

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, readwritelock, boost-exception

I have a program like `main.cpp`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class MutexClass
{
private:
    /* data */
    boost::shared_mutex m_mutex;
    bool running;   //The flag program should stop
public:
    MutexClass(/* args */);
    ~MutexClass();
    void doSomeThing();
};

MutexClass::MutexClass(/* args */)
{
    running = true;
    printf("MutexClass()\n");
}

MutexClass::~MutexClass()
{
    printf("~MutexClass\n");
    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    running = false;
}

void MutexClass::doSomeThing() {
    printf("doSomeThing\n");  //In fact, here is a callback or loop

    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(m_mutex); //(1)Exception here
    if(running){
        printf("still running!\n");
    }    
}

void doSomeThing(MutexClass* mtx) {
    sleep(3);
    mtx->doSomeThing();
}

void destroy(MutexClass* mtx) {
    sleep(2);
    delete mtx;
    mtx = NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MutexClass* mtx = new MutexClass();
    boost::thread thrd1(&doSomeThing,mtx);
    boost::thread thrd2(&destroy,mtx);
    thrd1.join();
    thrd2.join();
    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run this file with

> g++ main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -g -o main && ./main

It shows

```
MutexClass()
~MutexClass
doSomeThing
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
Aborted
```

I know it crash at line 33, the comment line in the function

```
void MutexClass::doSomeThing() {
    printf("doSomeThing\n");  //In fact, here is a callback or loop

    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(m_mutex); //Exception here
    if(running){
        printf("still running!\n");
    }    
}
```

Env: Boost Version is 1.54

**My question is**: The program is `multiple-read/single-write`, how can I avoid this when run doSomeThing in a different thread, if the MutexClass already run destructor.
And only can add **try/catch** block?
Thanks!

Comment: this seems to be the exact duplicate of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65378092/boost-multithreading-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by plenty of ways. The main goal here is not to `delete` your object until all the routines using it are dead. One of the method is using `shared_ptr` to pass the object into thread.

Take a look at what I'd done here to make this code work. I've commented the significant changes with !!!

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <thread>

class MutexClass
{
private:
    /* data */
    boost::shared_mutex m_mutex;
    bool running;   //The flag program should stop
public:
    MutexClass(/* args */);
    ~MutexClass();
    void doSomeThing();
    void stop() {       // !!! changing running to false moves to this method
        printf("stop()\n");
        boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        running = false;
    }   
};

MutexClass::MutexClass(/* args */)
{
    running = true;
    printf("MutexClass()\n");
}

MutexClass::~MutexClass()
{
    printf("~MutexClass\n");
}

void MutexClass::doSomeThing() {
    printf("doSomeThing\n");  //In fact, here is a callback or loop

    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(m_mutex); //(1)Exception here
    if (running) {
        printf("still running!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("not running!\n");
    }
}

void doSomeThing(std::shared_ptr<MutexClass> mtx) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    mtx->doSomeThing();
}

void destroy(std::shared_ptr<MutexClass> mtx) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    mtx->stop();        // !!! Stop instead of delete
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto mtx = std::make_shared<MutexClass>();  // !!! store mtx in shared ptr
    boost::thread thrd1(&doSomeThing, mtx);
    boost::thread thrd2(&destroy, std::move(mtx));  // !!! You can play with std::move here to see where your object is destroyed.
    thrd1.join();
    thrd2.join();
    printf("after join\n");     // before this line mtx object should be destroyed
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    //sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```